# Showing there is a prime in a ring extension using Nakayama's lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here's the problem that I'm working on:

> if $A \subset B$ is a finite ring extension and $P$ is a prime ideal of $A$ show there is a prime ideal $Q$ of $B$ with $Q \cap A = P$. (M. Reid, *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra*, Exercise 4.12(i))

There was a hint to use Nakayama's lemma to show $PB \not= B$, for that part what I've done is said $B$ is a finitely generated $A$ module, $P$ is an ideal of $A$ therefore I can apply NAK here and it tells me that: $PB = B$ implies that there exists some $r \in A$ satisfying $r \equiv 1 \pmod P$. I would need to get a contradiction from this but I wasn't able to see how.

> Any guidance on whether I am approaching this correctly and how to do the part I am stuck on would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Do you know Cohen Seidenberg theorems?

Comment: no i don't know that

Comment: I believe you're exercise is a part of the going up and down theorems?

Comment: Maybe. it's just stated as a problem in my book (reid - undergraduate commutative algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the contradiction comes from the fact that there exists $r\in A$ such $r=1+p, p\in P$ and $rB=0$ this implies $(1+p)A=0$ so for every $a\in A, (1+p)a=a+pa=0$ which implies $a\in P$ contradiction since $P$ is different of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part:
Since $A \subset B$ is a finite ring extension, $B$ is integral over $A$. Now you can use "*LYING-OVER THEOREM*", (*Atiyah-Macdonald*'s Theorem 5.10).

---

If you are interested in a direct proof you can derive it from propositions in section 5 of the book (*Atiyah-Macdonald*'s book: *Introduction To Commutative Algebra*) that leads to Theorem 5.10.  (see 5.1, 5.6, 5.8 and then 5.10. The proofs suggest using localization.)